# Machinist for Non-ActiveRecord Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, mocking, machinist

Is it possible to use Machinist to create blueprints for non-activerecord models?  Seems to generate an error no matter what I try!

If this is impossible with Machinist, is there another fixture generating gem that can do it?  I've also read that Factory Girl has issues with this.

Comment: It might be helpful if you produce the simplest example possible that reproduces the problem. Also, what do you mean by "non-activerecord models"? Something using ActiveModel, or something using Plain Old Ruby Objects?

Comment: I'm just referring to a model that is not tied to ActiveRecord/ActiveModel, but yes, you could really just say I'm looking for a way to use Machinist blueprints for just any regular Ruby Classes.  I know I could always make my own factory method using OpenStruct to do this, but I really like Machinist's syntax, and it would be nice if I could put everything under Machinist's blueprint.rb file.

Answer (score 4):

I did a little bit of investigating into Machinist 2 beta 1 and it looks like it supports plain ruby objects. Here's what I did to get it working. Happy to learn of any simpler solutions.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'machinist'
require 'faker'

class YourObject
 attr_accessor :field1, :field2
end


# For all Objects
class Object
 extend Machinist::Machinable

 def self.blueprint_class
   Machinist::Blueprint
 end
end   

# Or just one object
YourObject.send(:extend, Machinist::Machinable)
YourObject.class_eval do
 def self.blueprint_class
   Machinist::Blueprint
 end
end



YourObject.blueprint do
 field1 { rand(1000) }
 field2 { Faker::Name }
end

obj = YourObject.make
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's curious, one of the problems (there may be others) with FactoryGirl and POROs is that it doesn't handle constructors with arguments. You can make due per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838145/26819).