# How to resolve factory_girl wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

```
#rspec test code
@room = FactoryGirl.build(:room)

#factory definition
factory :room do
  length {10}
  width {20}
end

#code implementation
class Room
  attr_accessor :length, :width

  def initialize(length,width)
     @length = length
     @width = width 
  end

end
```

Running rspec results in this error when trying to build the @room

> > ArgumentError:
> >            wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FactoryGirl` does not currently support initializers with arguments. So it fails when it's trying to do `Room.new` when you run `build`.

One simple workaround for this might be to monkey-patch your classes in your test setup to get around this issue. It's not the ideal solution, but you'll be able to run your tests.

So you'd need to do either one of these (just in your test setup code):

```
class Room
   def initialize(length = nil, width = nil)
     ...
   end
end
```

or

```
class Room
  def initialize
    ...
  end
end
```

The issue is discussed here:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/42

...and here:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/19

Comment: Thank you, what an unexpected error, I was thinking its me :-)

Answer (score 23):

Now it does. Tested on version 4.1:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :room do
    length 10
    width 20
    initialize_with { new(length, width) }
  end
```

end

Reference: [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction)

Answer (score 1):

What was useful for me, was enabling debug output for FactoryBot linting:

```rb
FactoryBot.lint verbose: true
```

see [the documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories) for the details