# How to initialize class in block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out the proper block initialize

```
class Foo 
  attr_accessor :bar
end

obj = Foo.new do |a|
  a.bar = "baz"
end

puts obj.bar
```

Expect "baz"
instead get nil

What is the proper incantation for block class initializers in ruby?

Comment: The `attr_accessor` can't work in that form and the block is never called.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about that, I fixed it so it is "functional" code now

Comment: Right, I get that it doesn't get called (which explains why it doesn't work).  

I like the "tap" idea below, as it lets me use tools like FactoryGirl (which require default initializers) without having to override new.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give an example usage of `FactoryGirl` where this would be of advantage?

Comment: Here's some links on the problem [wrong # of args](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837761/how-to-resolve-factory-girl-wrong-number-of-arguments-error) [github discussion](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/42)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try again:

```
class Foo 
  attr_accessor :bar
end

obj = Foo.new.tap do |a|
  a.bar = "baz"
end

puts obj.bar
```

Comment: That's not the same. Also, it should raise a `NameError`.

Comment: It's the best way without adding new ways your users have to read the documentation for.

Comment: This way is better than putting `yield self if block_given?` in the Foo's initialize method, because often you can't or don't want to modify the Foo class (think of the Open Closed Principle).  Plus, why clutter up the initialize method of the Foo class, when a simple method chaining of `tap` would do?

Answer (score 30):

Another way to make a block initializer would be writing it yourself one:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

And later use it:

```
foo = Foo.new do |f|
  f.bar = true
end
```

My two cents.

Comment: no doubt this is the better way of initializing a class with a block.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I don't think `new` can take a block.</s> Never saw it anywhere anyway. Why do you want to initialize in a block ? You can always do `obj = foo.new.tap do |a| ...` If you really want a block

Comment: It's not that it *can't* take a block, it's just ugly. Despite this, it's a commonly seen "idiom".

Comment: Why is it ugly?  It's a common idiom in other languages that I've used such as c#.

Comment: @Doug: It's equally ugly in other languages, the main reason for it being that it doesn't serve any particular purpose and just increases complexity.

Comment: It seems clearer and less error-prone to me.  There's no order dependency as in a normal constructor, and you get named parameters which are easier to read and write.  

I'd probably only resort to a constructor if there was some initialization beyond copying in values (which is not always the case)

Answer (score 0):

actually you have a constructor for these purposes:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize(bar = "baz")
    @bar = bar
  end

end
```

Comment: Maybe you should actually make that a parameter.

Comment: Niklas, yeah, that would be better

Comment: It's not common pass them as constrcuter. Just look at some ruby code in github